# How much data to IP Cameras use

Tags: ip-camera

Is there any way of knowing how much data per month a motion detection IP camera will use? I don't know if it's actually "on" 24/7. When I had it hooked up before, I could view the live feed anytime I wanted and also, when motion was detected, it would send several snap shots to me via email. 
I'm trying to figure out the cheapest route to go when choosing an internet provider. I had Comcast, but their customer service sucks so bad that I had to cancel.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the resolution and encoding.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the model of IP camera. Also, remove the comment about Comcast and choosing an ISP, which are are off topic here per the [faq]. This may help avoid the question being closed.

Comment: regardless of the camera bandwidth usage... the cheapest route to go is the to sign up for the cheapest service provider... but if you want to calculate the usage all the same... look at the answer below...

Answer (score 1):

You ought to use a `network traffic monitoring tool` to get the bandwidth used by your camera both under normal conditions and during motion detection.

Then based on your usage of the camera you should be able to make a guess on its monthly data usage.